# Need advice in microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

I am studying electronic and communication engineering 
It's my second year
I really want to start in the field of microcontroller ,pic and pcb
And I am really interested in making robots
But I don't know what I should start with I already good at c++
But they say that I should learn c to program a PIC 
So can you tell me some titles of books or  courses that I should take 
Many thanks

Comment: Since you are at a university, why not ask your colleagues or some prof? There's usually some kind of academic adviser actually paid to help/answer questions like this from students. I'm sure they'll be happy to give you advice that will likely be better suited in terms of actual course[s] at your university etc. Also, book recommendations are generally off-topic on EE.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when microcontroller is programmed in c, it can be programmed in c++ as well, but not always. However, it would be of a great benefit to learn to program in C, if you are really into microcontrollers.

Since you are already quite good with C++, I would recommend to take a look at [mbed](http://mbed.org) microcontroller (programmed in c++). It is really nice microcontroller for any beginner into the field, since they have really nice written library for all peripherals that mbed has. This allows to jump into creating real life applications without much knowledge about actual internals of microcontroller and how all those low level registers work.

Later on, you could pick up another microcontroller that requires programming in C, and actual understanding of low level stuff (writing/reading into registers), paying great attention to all documentation of peripherals.